# emacs 27 (lucid toolkit) daemon crashes every couple of minutes

Tags: debugging, emacs-daemon, systemd-integration

Some variant of this has been asked before - emacs daemon crashing when it has been built with Gtk3 etc - but I couldn't find any solution to this.

I've built Emacs 27.1 from source on Xubuntu 20.04 with `--with-x-toolkit=lucid`. I then copied `emacs.service` into `$HOME/.config/system/user/` and ran `systemctl --user start emacs.service`.

It ran for a while and crashed with the following message:

```
Job for emacs.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl --user status emacs.service" and "journalctl --user -xe" for details.
```

Note: I don't need to open a file or resize emacs etc. The daemon fails even when I don't start an `emacsclient`.

The outputs of both the recommended commands are given below:

`journalctl`:

```
anaravi@anaravi-xxxxx:~$ journalctl --user -xe
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 249 and the job result is failed.
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx systemd[2390]: emacs.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit UNIT has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx systemd[2390]: Stopped Emacs text editor.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit UNIT has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit UNIT has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 265 and the job result is done.
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx systemd[2390]: Starting Emacs text editor...
-- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 265.
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/config/cfg-custom.el (source)...
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/config/cfg-custom.el (source)...done
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...done
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/recentf...
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/recentf...done
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Cleaning up the recentf list...
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Cleaning up the recentf list...done (0 removed)
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Starting Emacs daemon.
Dec 27 21:37:28 anaravi-xxxxx gnome-keyring-daemon[2403]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
Dec 27 21:37:39 anaravi-xxxxx gnome-keyring-daemon[2403]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
```

`systemctl`:

```
anaravi@anaravi-xxxxx:~$ systemctl --user status emacs
● emacs.service - Emacs text editor
     Loaded: loaded (/home/anaravi/.config/systemd/user/emacs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sun 2020-12-27 21:35:53 IST; 1min 16s ago
       Docs: info:emacs
             man:emacs(1)
             https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
   Main PID: 2890 (emacs)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/emacs.service
             └─2890 /usr/local/lib/emacs/27.1/bin/emacs --fg-daemon

Dec 27 21:35:57 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...
Dec 27 21:35:58 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/config/cfg-custom.el (source)...
Dec 27 21:35:58 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/config/cfg-custom.el (source)...done
Dec 27 21:36:02 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...done
Dec 27 21:36:02 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/recentf...
Dec 27 21:36:02 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/recentf...done
Dec 27 21:36:02 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Cleaning up the recentf list...
Dec 27 21:36:02 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Cleaning up the recentf list...done (0 removed)
Dec 27 21:36:07 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: Starting Emacs daemon.
Dec 27 21:36:18 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[2890]: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/local': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/local”: open() failed: No such file or di>
anaravi@anaravi-xxxxx:~$ systemctl --user status emacs
● emacs.service - Emacs text editor
     Loaded: loaded (/home/anaravi/.config/systemd/user/emacs.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sun 2020-12-27 21:37:26 IST; 3s ago
       Docs: info:emacs
             man:emacs(1)
             https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
   Main PID: 3264 (emacs)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/emacs.service
             └─3264 /usr/local/lib/emacs/27.1/bin/emacs --fg-daemon

Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx systemd[2390]: Starting Emacs text editor...
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/config/cfg-custom.el (source)...
Dec 27 21:37:26 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/config/cfg-custom.el (source)...done
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/init.el (source)...done
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/recentf...
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Loading /home/anaravi/.emacs.d/recentf...done
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Cleaning up the recentf list...
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Cleaning up the recentf list...done (0 removed)
Dec 27 21:37:27 anaravi-xxxxx emacs[3264]: Starting Emacs daemon.
```

Comment: Typically any Emacs crash implies an Emacs bug. Consider reporting this: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem in the configuration status while building:

```
  ...
  Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   yes
  Does Emacs use -lsystemd?                               no
  Does Emacs use -ljansson?                               yes
  Does Emacs use -lgmp?                                   yes
  ...
```

Emacs was built without **lsystemd** because I was missing `libsystemd-dev`. Installing that package seems to have solved the problem.